# Angular 2 multiple custom value accessor

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, ng-bootstrap, maskedinput

I am creating an application using angular2.

I need to get a Date from user input using a calendar popover, but I need to put a mask on user input to stay in this format dd-mm-YYYY when he is typing.

I am using two different modules that I got from web ***ng-bootstrap*** and ***angular2-text-mark***

```
<input [textMask]="{mask: mask}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
         name="dp" [(ngModel)]="date" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
```

When I use ***textMask*** and ***ngbDatepicker*** on same tag I get this error

> ERROR: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute.

Is there a way to do this kind of things ?

Thanks

Comment: which is the angular version ? try the ngDefaultControl attribute to your input.

Comment: Version 2.4. Are you saying for not use ngModel ? Still not working. The problem is when I use **textMask** and **ngbDatepicker**. Seems that Angular cannot support two directives from different packages.

Comment: @RafaelAndrade - did you found the solution for this? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't have a solution until today.
Here is what i've done to still be able to use a MASKED INPUT and a Ngb DATEPICKER,
I've created two inputs, one with the masked input, the other with the datepicker.
Whenever a value changes, they both update the main object (wich used to be the `ngModel` bind.

Here is the code. I hope it helps someone.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control form-control-sm"
    [(ngModel)]="begin_date"
    (change)="onDateInput($event.target.value)"
    placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"
    [textMask]="{mask: maskedInput.date}"
  >
  <input
    type="hidden"
    (dateSelect)="onDateSelect($event)"
    [(ngModel)]="object.begin"
    ngbDatepicker
    #dI="ngbDatepicker"
  >
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <button
      class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm"
      (click)="dI.toggle()"
      type="button"
    >
      <i
        class="fa fa-calendar"
        aria-hidden="true"
      ></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem. I have used "ngx-datepicker with mask".I removed ngModel from the input and it's working absolutely fine.

Answer (score -3):

Rafael, I had the same issue, my solution was set the input to readonly and allow the user to choose the date only using the calendar.

```html
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <label>End Date</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" (click)="dpEndDate.toggle()">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </span>
    <input readonly required [(ngModel)]="model.endDate" 
      type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate"
      name="endDate" ngbDatepicker #dpEndDate="ngbDatepicker">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: :) sometimes change the requirements is the solution

Comment: I decided to use a place holder with how user should type the date. If he type something like 11/03/1992 my form will not allow him to go to next page. Or he types using ' - ' or he uses the calendar.