# Angular 4 multiple custom value accessor

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular2-forms

This question relates to the question that has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375274/angular-2-multiple-custom-value-accessor), but has not been answered.

I am using Angular 4.2 to run a POC with *Kendo UI For Angular*. Same as the author of the above question, i need to change the date format in the model, for which i have created a custom attribute directive "*formatDate*" which uses **ControlValueAccessor**. And i have used

```
multi: true
```

option as well in the directive. The current code looks like this;

```
 <kendo-datepicker [(ngModel)] = "myModel" formatDate></kendo-datepicker>
```

When i run this, i get the same error as;

> ERROR Error:More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute

I tested "*formatDate*" directive with a simple HTML5 date input before and it worked fine.I reckon that kendo datepicker might also be using ControlValueAccessor as well, and hence i am getting this error.

Seems the error is popping up from [angular/forms/directives/shared.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d2ad871279c410334314def0be5c5d0599f4368e/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L157). And there's a comment on the top of the function "**selectValueAccessor**" mentioning a particular issue in github **(github.com/angular/angular/issues/3011)**. And it pointed out to another issue **(github.com/angular/angular/issues/3009)** which talks about implementing formatters/parsers for angular. There's a new npm library introduced by someone a few days ago, but i am not sure if i want to go through all that hassle to do something trivial.

Has anyone experienced this issue and came up with any solution on how to support multiple control value accessors?.

Comment: Have you tried using existing ControlValueAccessor by injection it in your directive?

Comment: you mean without implementing the ControlValueAccessor interface?

Comment: There's no way to input have more than one value accessor atleast for now.